# Copiar imágenes en PHP

Tags: php

Me edito y dejo el código como lo tengo ahora. He seguido haciendo pruebas y con el siguiente código se copian pero salen las imágenes vacias. Como explicación, tengo un ciclo a la base de datos (Donde guardo las rutas, nombres de las imágenes..etc). La variable ruta_foto incluye el directorio y el archivo.

```
            $ruta_foto = $dafo['ruta'];
            $nombre_archivo = $dafo['solo_nombre'].".png";
            $ubicacion_inicial = "temporal/".$id_usuario;
           $ubicacion_final = 'api_movil/'.$datos_cliente->ruta_cliente."/".$save."/";
             if (!file_exists($ubicacion_final)) {
                 mkdir($ubicacion_final, 0775, true);
             }
             $ruta_final = $ubicacion_final.$nombre_archivo ;
            //Lo movemos
            //move_uploaded_file($ruta_foto, $ruta_finalisima);
            $mover = copy($ruta_foto, $ruta_final );
```

Desconozco si debo dejar el texto anterior, por precaución lo dejo. Gracias.

tengo unas imágenes en un directorio y necesito moverlas a otro. El problema que tengo es que me crea los directorios necesarios pero no me copia las imágenes, ¿Sabeis que está fallando?

```
<?php 
          $ubicacion_inicial = "temporal/".$id_usuario;
          //Ahora la vamos a mover a la ruta del cliente
          $ubicacion_final = 'clientes/'.$datos_cliente->ruta_fotos."/".$id;
          if (!file_exists($ubicacion_final)) {
              mkdir($ubicacion_final, 0775, true);
          }
         //Lo movemos
          move_uploaded_file($ubicacion_inicial, $ubicacion_final);
```

Comment: Una [*Ruta*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruta_\(inform%C3%A1tica\)) puede hacer referencia a un archivo o a un directorio; ¿A qué hacen referencia `$ubicacion_*`?.

Comment: En este caso hace referencia al Directorio

Comment: ¿porque usas `move_uploaded_file()` en lugar de `rename()`?

Comment: lo que quiero es moverlos y rename, segun veo, es para renombrarlos

Comment: Ya, eso es lo que pone en [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.rename.php), en la primera frase, pero léete la segunda un poco más abajo

Comment: ¿Quieres mover o quieres copiar los archivos? Si quieres moverlos, lo propio es que uses `rename()`, como ya te indicó @masterguru en su comentario. Si quieres copiar, entonces usa `copy()`. En cualquier caso, debes asegurarte que la ruta de cada archivo es correcta (para depurar puedes imprimir las rutas y verificar) y asegurarte de que tienes los permisos suficientes para leer / escribir en los directorios en cuestión. Si el código sigue sin funcionar, entonces revisa el log de errores y dinos qué ves en él.

Comment: Me ha servido, muchas gracias (NOTA MENTAL- Leer las documentaciones hasta el final)